# Why ThreadPool has 250 worker threads per processor by default?

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool, processor

Taken from Microsoft documentation:

> By default, the thread pool has 250 worker threads per available processor. You can
>   change this setting using the ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads method.

It's also said, as it's widely known, that there is some overhead:

> Threads have some level of overhead. Therefore, if a computer has multiple processors
>   and you split processing into two threads, you won’t see a 100 percent performance
>   improvement.

Out of some experience and more out of guessing, I'd have had something like **1 to 4** threads per CPU, and not **250**! Does someone know why 250? Is it some value that is supposed to give the **best overall performance**, *or* is it in order to have pretty much every task you give to that thread pool to be **processed without waiting** for other tasks to finish?

Comment: I think better to ask @serverfault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The motivation isn't performance. As you've mentioned, having too much threads can easily cause a performance degradation (due to context switching, cache thrashing, contentions etc.).
The idea behind this magical number is the attempt to avoid deadlocks from appearing in the user's code. A developer might cause a deadlock if it queues numerous work items to a thread pool that waits on other items that were queue to the thread pool also. If a situation occurs where the thread pool have utilized its max number of threads (they are all in Wait state), then you've got yourself a **deadlock**.

Of course there isn't anything special with the number "250", and deadlocks may still occur if the developer insists on using such a problematic usage pattern of the thread pool. However, it should decrease the chance to reach a deadlock in such scenarios.

Joe Duffy explains this reasoning in more depth in his post: [Why the CLR 2.0 SP1's threadpool default max thread count was increased to 250/CPU](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/03/04/why-the-clr-20-sp1s-threadpool-default-max-thread-count-was-increased-to-250cpu/).